# Android - Localized text search using english alphabet

Tags: android, localization

I have tried to google for this but I don't know exactly what to look for. The Android app I am working on uses localized text. Some users use English keyboard only and can't use localised characters for search. So if they want to search for the phrase "čađ" they type "cad". So there is a need to convert "čađ" to "cad" to find a phrase successfully.

My question is how this feature or functionality is called.  Is there any Android library doing this?

I have a pretty good idea of how to implement this, but if a solution already exists, I think it is better to use it.

Comment: Just a linguistic note here-  just because you, a non speaker, think that c and č are the same does not mean that the people who speak that language will.  So doing this, even if you get it right, can lead to nonsensical results.

Comment: @GabeSechan Trust me I know what I'm talking about, it's  my native language. You also have to believe me that there are a lot of people who only use an English keyboard and write in Serbian. That is why this question was asked.

Comment: And there's also people in Germany who see u and ü and don't see them as the same letter.  If you have a specific use case in mind it might be ok, but implementing this as a generic cross language feature is something you should talk to trained linguists about first, to determine if it will actually help or cause more confusion.

Comment: As I said before, I know exactly what I'm talking about and I know how people here think and behave in a specific case. Very often people write in Serbian using a non-Serbian, more precisely English/US keyboard. And they understand each other very well. I can't talk about the German language because I don't speak it and I don't use it.